# Prevent Visual Studio editor from reformatting #if ... #endif

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

Assuming I have the following code in C#:

```
void Func () {
    int i=3;

    #if DEBUG
    ...
    #endif

    for (int j=0;j<i;j++) {
        ...
    }
}
```

If I use `Edit->Advanced->Format document`, it gets reformatted to this (using my current code formatting settings):

```
void Func ()
{
    int i = 3;

#if DEBUG
    ...
#endif

    for ( int j = 0; j < i; j++ )
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Is there a way to prevent the `#if` and `#endif` lines from being moved to the far left? I couldn't find any settings for these but I'm hoping there's a registry setting that controls how this works.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated - this behavior drives me crazy since my code has several hundred such blocks, they keep getting broken by VS.

Comment: It formats perfectly fine :) the #statements are NOT part of the code so they shouldn't be indented.

Comment: That's your preference. When you have hundreds of these (5-9 per function on the average) it makes it very hard to read the code. It's near impossible to even find the beginning/end of functions.

Comment: here's a suggestion - http://msmvps.com/blogs/peterritchie/archive/2011/11/24/if-you-re-using-if-debug-you-re-doing-it-wrong.aspx

Comment: @hatchet That doesn't help when I have an existing source base of a few thousand source files. Plus some functions are called in multiple contexts in some situations so I cannot just tag a function as DEBUG-only.

Comment: Have you looked at http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/sourceanalysis

"StyleCop analyzes C# source code to enforce a set of style and consistency rules. It can be run from inside of Visual Studio or integrated into an MSBuild project "

Comment: @Standage thanks, but that's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: If you have hundreds of these lines, I suspect the structure of your code. You might be able to factor these out into separate functions/classes and use a pattern such as DI/IoC to switch between implementations or perhaps you could use the `[Conditional]` attribute.

Comment: @Erno no, the structure of the code is fine. The same code has to be built for 7 different configurations. Short of maintaining 7 separate sets of files (~10,000 source files), there's no other way in C# to do this. Even if I assume that some of it could be done, it still doesn't solve the problem of Visual Studio messing up the code layout.

Comment: Ok, I understand (I have to because I don't know the code). However I still think that VS does NOT mess up the code.

Comment: No offence intended but this is just being pedantic. +1 to Erno & Hatchet. -1 for using pre-compiler directives as logic flow which is extremely poor practice. It can be cleaned up as per hatchet's advice, which you're reluctant to do. Heck, create global static constants instead of pre-compiler directives and change all your #if statements to if() statements and problem solved. You'll still have crap code, but it will indent pretty. It'll compile a bit bigger, but hey, hard drives are cheap especially compared to the development costs needed to maintain stuff like that.

Comment: I would love to be able to customize this as well. I don't normally use #if DEBUG, but multi-targeting code for several platforms you sometimes really need preprocessing directives.

Answer (score 2):

one style that I've been using is adding space to the # tag like this

```
void Func ()
{
    int i = 3;

#   if DEBUG
    ...
#   endif

    for ( int j = 0; j < i; j++ )
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

..the if block looks like its lined up with the code correctly and re-formatting code doesn't move the preprocessor tags.

Comment: @com3lius: I only saw your suggestion now, thanks - I'll give this a try. I'm not sure if I like it but it still looks better than VS butchering the layout.